# Use residuals of regression to calculate another regression (inside function) in R

Tags: r, function, regression

I'm using a function to calculate regressions. I need the residuals a relationship to relate to another variable. 
This is because I change the facet grid several times.

This is my code:

```
modelregression = function(file) {
mod2 = lm(y ~ x,data=file)
mod = lm(mod2$residuals ~ anotherX,data=file)
mod_sum = summary(mod)
formula = sprintf("y= %.3f %+.3f*x",
                coef(mod)[1], coef(mod)[2])
r = mod_sum$r.squared
r2 = sprintf("r2= %.3f", r)
x  = cor.test(~mod2$residuals + anotherX,data=file)
r0 = sprintf("r= %.3f", x[4])
p1 = pf(mod_sum$fstatistic[1],mod_sum$fstatistic[2],mod_sum$fstatistic[3],lower.tail=F)
p =sprintf("p = %.3f", p1)
n0 = length(mod_sum$residual)
n1 = sprintf("N = %.f", n0)
data.frame(formula=formula, r=r0,r2=r2, p=p,n=n1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

modelregression_math = ddply(file, c("database","level"), modelregression)
```

The it runs without any problem, but all coefficients are zero. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the residuals to reside "inside" what is specified by `data=`.
Thus, insert a line like the follwing before running the second regression:

```
file <- cbind(mod2$residuals, file)
```

However, this will only work if the lines in `file` will match the order and amount of lines in what is used for the 1st regression. If you have missing values, it gets more complicated: Use `mod2$model` to get exactly the data used in the regression (also in the right order) and combine that with the residuals:

```
data_with_residuals <- cbind(mod2$model, mod2$residuals)
mod = lm(residuals ~ anotherX, data=data_with_residuals)
```

(Or an approach with `merge()` could do the trick.)

Comment: As I do it (cbind) off function all right!
But within the function gives the same error!
code

modelregression = function (file) {
mod2 = lm (y ~ x, data = file)
file <- cbind (mod2$residuals, file)
mod = lm(mod2$residuals ~ anotherX, data = file)

Comment: leave out "mod2$" in the regression formula, so the variable "residuals" from file is taken.

Comment: This way works, but the regression values are calculated incorrectly.
This is because for every facet of the grid should have their specific residuals